# moving water away from gutter downspout

Tags: drain, gutters, downspout

I have a dip around one of my downspouts and I have a lot of water gathering in that area when it rains. It's coming from gutter downspout and neighbors gutters.
I want to install water collector (catch basin) in that area and attach my downspout to it as well.
I want to direct all this water to the back side of my backyard away from the house(I have landscape inclination towards that area).

1. Do I need a french drain for that (corrugated drain pipe with fabric filter and stone) or I can just use 4'' pipe without holes in it just to move the water away and maybe add a water collector in the end with stones?
2. What are consequences if I use drain pipe with holes wrapped in fabric but without stones? (I don't wanna use that much stone for the project)  As I understand the worst can happen is the water won't escape from holes fast enough but the pipe won't clogged, right?

Comment: It's not really a downhill,  there is a hill before the dip which is not allowing water to go away from the house :) that's why I wanna install a drain there

Answer (score 2):

No one *needs* a French drain. You can move the water however you like. BTW, a French drain is simply an underground drain that surfaces somewhere. It has nothing to do with types of pipe or socks.

Corrugated pipe, even with a sock, can certainly silt in over time without enough slope. The sock isn't magic. If there's a low/slow spot and suspended particles can settle out, it'll fill up within a few years. That's the primary reason for using a bed of washed rock--to delay the inevitable. It also creates reservoir space for drain water, but if you daylight the drain that's probably not important here.